# jQuery parent() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, markup

Consider the following HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>FOO</legend>
    <div> <!-- this is not static code...it's generated by jQuery-->
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I run this jQuery

```
console.log($("#chkBox").parent());
```

I get `[Fieldset]` instead of the expected `[div]`...and I have no idea why!?

**EDIT:** Just a quick point here...the `<div>` tag is being generated by jQuery...so in reality, the fieldset IS the parent (hard-coded)...so how would I get the dynamically created parent?

Comment: And I get the div -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WBF6B/1/). Check for typos, unclosed elements etc. For instance `</ledgend>` ?

Comment: It's working for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/6p5Et/

Comment: You didn't properly close your `legend` tag, you mispelled it. Probably messing up in whatever browser you're testing.

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, that was a typo...which is now corrected.

Comment: tested you example and it worked fine... are you sure that's the exact HTML you are having trouble with?

Comment: You mention the `<div` tag is generated dynamically. Is the checkbox generated dynamically as well. If not, are you sure the div tag is correctly wrapping the checkbox? I would suggest you view the content in the console, such as using Chrome's **Inspect Element** feature to make sure your DOM looks like the code above.

Comment: I think your are trying to read the fieldset's parent before you added the div.
Sometimes js is tricky and maybe some code have been executed before the other, even if it seems otherwise.

Comment: @War10ck, your last comment solved the problem, so thank you very much! :-) add as answer and I will accept.

Comment: @series0ne Glad to hear it buddy. It's been added as an answer below. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the `<div>` tag is generated dynamically. If the checkbox is not generated dynamically as well, it will cause the added `<div>` tag to not properly wrap the checkbox.

View the content in Chrome's **Inspect Element** tool, or any other browser's equivalent (i.e. FireBug) and make sure the dynamically generated content alters the DOM to create the output you expect as you posted in your question above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. My logic was a bit backward. it was performing the parent() operation before nesting the input tag into the div, hence, it was getting the fieldset as the parent. +1 and accepted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem buddy. Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your HTML

```
<legend>FOO</ledgend>
```

This could be causing parsing errors which means your DOM isn't what you think it is.

Comment: that was a typo on SO...not solving the issue.

Comment: See War10ck's comment...that solved the issue.

Comment: Fair enough - thanks!